# Why haven't I received my rep back after a bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I posted a bounty on a question and received no answers within a week.  The bounty ended, but I still have 66 rep.

Why is this? It says in the [Bounty Part of the FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) that:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone

So why didn't I get my rep back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Keep reading:

> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation
>   specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow
>   up and award your bounty to the best answer!

When a bounty is not awarded to anyone, they do not return to the awarder, they are simply lost. There is no conservation of reputation.

Comment: That sucks....... Guess Ill just have to earn it back;)

Comment: Is there any place where we can see why this was decided so? i.e Any place the discussion relating to this decision is archived?

Comment: @rahul Bearing in mind that it has been 8 years since you asked that follow-up question and this may not explicitly answer it, the closest thing appears to be [this FAQ answer about bounties on the SE Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/341145)